# Stata : distinct values, count and histogram

Tags: stata

I am new to Stata and still learning.
I have a var shaped like that :

```
+-------+
| Phase |
+-------+
| I     |
+-------+
| I     |
+-------+
| II    |
+-------+
| III   |
+-------+
| II    |
+-------+
```

My goal is to draw a histogram with the possible value (I,II,III) (x-axis) and the number of each (2,2,1) (y-axis).

I though I could make a loop and store the number of each possible in an array but arrays does not seem to be implemented in Stata.

Is the any kind of function that do what I want already implemented or I have to write a function to distinct the value, then count them, then draw the histogram ?

Thank you.

/edit :

```
processed.p |
       hase |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          I |        266        0.92        0.92
       I/II |      1,006        3.50        4.42
         II |     10,867       37.76       42.18
     II/III |        344        1.20       43.37
        III |      9,248       32.13       75.51
         IV |      6,984       24.27       99.77
         NA |         65        0.23      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |     28,780      100.00
```

I found a way of counting distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

```
tab processedphase, matcell(x)
```

in order to obtain

```
processed.p |
       hase |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          I |        266        0.92        0.92
       I/II |      1,006        3.50        4.42
         II |     10,867       37.76       42.18
     II/III |        344        1.20       43.37
        III |      9,248       32.13       75.51
         IV |      6,984       24.27       99.77
         NA |         65        0.23      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |     28,780      100.00
```

then :

```
matrix list x
svmat x
```